# the meaning of multiple threading on single core cpu

Tags: c++, multithreading

Once I thought the only occasion multiple threads should be used is when IO processing is needed.

But I heard it's also useful without IO processing. Because it helps to occupy more CPU resources.

In my understanding, this would be

```
the process with more threads are given more CPU time.
```

Is this why multiple threads help improve performance even on single core?

Comment: Um, you get more chance to cuddle with the scheduler? :)

Comment: even some of the single cores can execute multiple threads. see hyper-threading.

Comment: A well designed single process / single threaded app can make a CPU scream if it takes care to minimize cache misses and such.  I think it really depends on how the code is written and micro optimizations

Comment: The hardware operations are so fast that the operating system is able to pretend that multiple CPUs exist since the bottle neck isn't the CPU itself, but rather the machine instructions being used.  By scheduling instructions in optimizing ways you can make execution go faster sequentially, but appear in parallel since multiple sets of instructions are executing very quickly in an interleaved manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible reason you can see greater performance from multiple threads on a single CPU is that CPUs tend to be really good at instruction reordering and making use of instruction-level parallelism.  Threads have fewer data and control dependencies with respect to one another than any two sequential instructions within a single thread, and therefore they offer more possibilities for the CPU and OS-level schedulers and re-ordering mechanisms to be very clever.

Don't forget that things like "reads and writes in memory" are still "I/O" when viewed in a particular way.  These are relatively slow operations, and much of the pipelining in modern CPUs is used to hide memory latency - having multiple threads executing at once can be useful for filling up time that would otherwise have to be filled with delay slots where there are data hazards within a single thread.

That said, threads are often *not* a good solution to increase performance, and can have precisely the opposite effect.  It can be very easy to saturate all available memory bandwidth using a single thread on some problems.

Comment: ' things like "reads and writes in memory" are still "I/O" ' - yes, but they are invisible to the OS and don't create context switches. so with a single core you will be stuck at waiting for the memory.

Comment: All of this answer seems to be predicated on the processor in question having hyperthreading.  Without hyperthreading the OS schedules only one thread at a time, as pointed out by @KarolyHorvath.

Comment: It would be hard, but with two threads I could carefully prefetch memory, then sleep, letting the other thread run, and returning when my memory has been loaded.  In effect, I manually trigger the scheduler.  Much care would have to be taken to avoid that prefetched memory from being discarded, and in pracice this may be impossible.

Comment: @Yakk: but I can't think of a system where a DRAM prefetch is of longer latency than an OS syscall (to do the yield).  You could do what you are talking about with [fibers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science)) (non-pre-emptive user-level threads) or coroutines.